# .remove and .append issue, .append not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove an element then later reattach it but append doesn't seem to be attaching it.

```
$("#full_image ul").remove();
   .....
   ........
   ............
 $('#full_image ul').append('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>');
```

Comment: The top line is removing the `ul`. The bottom line is attaching something to the `ul`s which still exist (which unless you added a new one in between is none). What are you trying to do?

Comment: `.remove` is removing the entire `ul`, not just an `li` inside of it.

Comment: maybe you meant to use `.empty()`?

Comment: Thank you Dave! I could kiss you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the element so it's not there anymore and you can't append anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#full_image ul").remove();
```

this removes the ul itself, not what's inside of it.

try something like this instead

```
$('#full_image ul').empty();
```

Comment: better to use `.empty()` than `.html('')`; it's clearer in its intent, simpler and shorter.

Comment: edited because I realised that html() was useless here ;) thanks. And you seemed to have posted it before I did in the comments, credits to you

Comment: Or even better skip `.empty` and just use `$('#full_image ul').html('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>')`